# There is no 'app\oracle\products\...' folder in C drive

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have downloaded Oracle SQL developer. When I try to create a new connection, it shows error as

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection.

I tried default usernames and passwords such as `SYS`, `SYSTEM` and `hr`. But none of them worked. I tried setting all the environment variables properly. I tried to login through sqlplus. Nothing worked. Searched in system services, no services are present with name `oracle` or `oracle services`.

There is no folder named `app` in C drive to set `ORACLE_PATH` or `ORACLE_HOME`. There is no path such as `c:\app\oracle\product...`. I have searched for `oracle\product\...` folder in other directories also. But I could not find any such folders.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to? Do you have a local or remote Oracle DB instance available? SQL Developer is just a client.

Comment: Wrote this just for you, good luck! https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303

Comment: Installing Oracle SQL Developer does not install the Oracle database. If you want to run Oracle locally you will have to install the Oracle database